# Can a user change screen name?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I recently looked back at a question that had an answer from a well known user and the answers is still there but instead of the old familiar moniker there us a user number.
It seems he changed his handle 
Is that allowed?

Answer (score 6):

That happens when a user deletes their account.  See [what EXACTLY happens when I ask to delete my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131665/what-exactly-happens-when-i-ask-to-delete-my-account/131666#131666)

Also, yes, we can change our screen name.  I changed mine a while back from my full name to just my first name. Just go to your profile and click "Edit Profile & Settings" then you can change the name listed in the "Display name field". You are only allowed to change it once every 30 days.

[image: Edit username]

Comment: Didn't want us to find you, huh? Well, too late! I already know! And I'm coming for you. Bwa hahaha!